# Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix, and suppose $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are orthogonal eigenvectors of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that $A\vec{v}$ and $A\vec{w}$ are orthogonal as well.

I don't have more information than that. I have been thinking about manipulating this equation 
$A^TA\vec{v} = k\vec{v}$ to get a dot product equal to zero somehow, but I don't get anywhere.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by “$\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are orthogonal vectors of $A^TA$”?

Comment: Don't want to be pedantic, but your question is closely related to the Singular Value Decomposition. If interested, search more about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't even need both of them to be eigenvectors:
$$
Av\cdot Aw = (Av)^tAw=v^tA^tAw=v^t\lambda w=\lambda v \cdot w=0
$$where $\cdot$ is the scalar product.